# Meaning of the roshei teivot והיע"ב אכי"ר

Tags: language, acronyms

The second part of the *reshei tevot* והיע"ב אכי"ר is of course *amen kein yehi ratzon* "so it may be His will", but I do not know the first part, היע"ב. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: ה' ירחם עלינו במהרה

Comment: Oh, thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use it for וה' יאיר עיני בתורתו.

Comment: To be honest, this should be left as a comment.

Comment: @Shmuel It is an answer. Considering I've never seen anyone else use it, it might be the  best one you find.